# How to consume an already implemented set of REST APIs in Next.js 13+ (App Router)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am currently working on a dashboard project based on React and React-router. The dashboard is all rendered on the client and it uses REST APIs implemented in Laravel.

I am considering recreating the same dashboard using Next.js 14.

I couldn't figure out a way of using those already implemented REST APIs in Next.js 14.

For example how can we implement authentication?

Is there any pattern to do this the right way?